# How to pass a string array from javascript to asp.net webservice?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, google-chrome-extension

I am creating Google Chrome Extension Project. I have a string array and I want to pass this array to my web service and take the array again. How can I do this? Should I need a database for this or I can communicate directly between them?

```
function myFunction(selectedText) {

var selected = selectedText.selectionText;
var yenidizi = new Array();
var words = new Array(); // This is my array and I want to pass this array to my web service.

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{

    for (var j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++)
    {
            var newstring = words[i];
                var temp = null;
                words[i] = temp;
                temp = newstring;
                words[i] = temp;
                newstring = null;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Look up AJAX. Also, you should replace `new Array()` with `[]`. It's the preferred way to generate arrays in JS.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to have a look at [Getting Started AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), code would be something like the following

```
var yourArray = [,];
$.post(url, { data: yourArray}, function (response) {
    // your callback here
}, "text");
```